# message sent but not received socket.on(...) for client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

(Working) I can see the message was sent to the server just fine:

[image]

```
// function used in reactjs(client)
const sendMessage = () => {
  const data = {
    room: room,
    content: {
      author: userName,
      message: message
    }
  }
  Promise.resolve(socket.emit('send_message', data))
  .then(() => setMessage(''));
}

useEffect(() => {
  socket.on('receive_message', data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}, []);
```

```
// function used in index.js(server)
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id);

  socket.on('join_room', (roomName) => {
    socket.join(roomName); // creates room with the name
    console.log('User Joined Room:', roomName);
  });

  socket.on('send_message', (data) => {
    console.log("data =", data);
    socket.to(data.room).emit('receive_message', data.content);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('USER DISCONNECTED')
  });
});
```

(Problem) Can anyone tell me why `receive_message` is not showing up in the console.log?

- Note: it will only show if I do something like add some comment to the react file and save it.(weird)

### The Full Code of both files

index.js(server)

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
const httpServer = createServer(app);

const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: true,
  origins: ['http://localhost:3000']
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id);

  socket.on('join_room', (roomName) => {
    socket.join(roomName); // creates room with the name
    console.log('User Joined Room:', roomName);
  });

  socket.on('send_message', (data) => {
    console.log("data =", data);
    socket.to(data.room).emit('receive_message', data.content);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('USER DISCONNECTED')
  });
});

httpServer.listen(3002, () => console.log(`Socket.io test running on port 3002`))
```

app.js(client)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import './App.css';

let socket = io('localhost:3002/');

function App() {
  // variables
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [room, setRoom] = useState('');
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [messageList, setMessageList] = useState([]);

  // functions
  const connectToRoom = () => {
    console.log('button clicked');
    setLoggedIn(true);
    socket.emit('join_room', room); // join_room copied from backend
  }

  const sendMessage = () => {
    const data = {
      room: room,
      content: {
        author: userName,
        message: message
      }
    }
    Promise.resolve(socket.emit('send_message', data))
    .then(() => setMessage(''));
  }

  // setup
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('receive_message', data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {!loggedIn ?
        <div className="logIn">
          <div className="inputs">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name..." value={userName} onChange={ev => setUserName(ev.target.value)} />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Room..." value={room} onChange={ev => setRoom(ev.target.value)} />
          </div>
          <button onClick={connectToRoom}>Enter Chat</button>
        </div> :
        <div className="chatContainer">
          <div className="messages">
            <h1>{room}</h1>
            {messageList.map((messageInfo, index) => 
              <div key={index} className="messageBox">
                <p>{messageInfo.author}:&nbsp;{messageInfo.message}</p>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="messageInputs">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Message..." value={message} onChange={ev => setMessage(ev.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={sendMessage}>Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: With "not received" I assume  you mean that `console.log(data);` didn't output anything?

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs that's right. Only after I write some comment in the app.js file and save it, will it show up in the console... and then magically everything continues to work fine... until I refresh the page.

Comment: Is `app.js` part of your server or client code?

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs client > https://github.com/jamespagedev/reactjs-with-socketio (I was weary about posting this repo on the problem because repo's change...)

Comment: Hmm not sure what's going on. I thought the server was restarting which was causing the issue, but it's the client that's reloading? But hot reloading, not a full page reload?

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs I can join a room. I can enter a message and click send. The message shows up on the server. When the server sends the message back to the client to use for console.log... the message does not appear in the console. Only after making a small file change to the app.js and saving the file, the message appears in the console, the room doesn't log out, and you can continue to send/receive messages normally. However doing a refresh will take you out of the room(as it should), causing a disconnect for the socket to be called(as it should), and now back to the same issue from start.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. The state is managed in two different places on the client side.

For the `socket.on('receive_message', ...)` in `useEffect`, this will show up on every single other browser console logged into the current room except the current browser's console(the browser sending the message).

To also get it to show in current console browser window, I also needed to add the state in where I am submitting it.

```
const sendMessage = () => {
  const data = {
    room: room,
    content: {
      author: userName,
      message: message
    }
  }
  Promise.resolve(socket.emit('send_message', data))
  .then(() => console.log(data)) // <------- add this line here
  .then(() => setMessage(''));
}
```

This of course means `setMessageList` will need to be called both inside the `sendMessage()` and the `socket.on('receive_message',...)`(within the `useEffect()`)

However, be careful when calling `setMessageList` inside `socket.on('receive_message',...)`. The reasons for this is because it is called within a single useEffect one time, it captures the state from when that function was called and will not update. In other words, you cannot use `setMessageList([...messageList, data])` because this function will only read `messageList` from when this function was first called initially.

To get around this, I see two options...

1. You can remove the `[]` inside the `useEffect((...), [])` forcing it to run in an infinite loop (this seems expensive).
2. The other option is to have the data on the backend update, save, then send back to which the `setMessageList(data)`(inside `socket.on('receive_message',...)`) will have to reload all the messages and re-render them all. (still seems expensive, but not as much as the first option)